# Kivy One-Folder packaging with PyInstaller looks for _MEIxxxxxx path?

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Looking to package a kivy application on windows, I ran `PyInstaller --onedir <app-name>.spec` on the following spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['temp-dir-for-packaging\\main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='one-folder',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('temp-dir-for-packaging\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas, 
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='one-folder')
```

It generated files under dist directory. However, when I run the resulting exe, I get the following error:

```
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI86482\python39.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

According to the [PyInstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-folder-program-works), the default i.e, `--onedir` option **should not** create a temporary _MEIxxxxxx directory to begin with.

Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there may be some confusion with `.spec` files. According to the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files):

> When you create a spec file, most command options are encoded in the
> spec file. When you build from a spec file, those options cannot be
> changed. If they are given on the command line they are ignored and
> replaced by the options in the spec file.
>
> Only the following command-line options have an effect when building
> from a spec file:
>
> --upx-dir
>
> --distpath
>
> --workpath
>
> --noconfirm
>
> --ascii
>
> --clean

The `spec` file that you posted is for creating a `onedir` executable, and adding the `--onedir` option has no effect.

I suggest removing the `build` and `dist` folders, along with the `.spec` file. Then create a new `spec` file using `pyi-makespec --onedir`.Then edit that newly created `.spec` file as needed. Then run `pyinstaller <app-name>.spec` with no command line options. This should create a `dist` folder with nothing in it other than another folder with the name of your main python file. Inside that folder you should find all the files needed to run your app, including a `python39.dll` file and an `exe` file.

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem, and indeed, it bundled python39.dll within the app folder this time.